# Highcharts showing ticks number, instead of date

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to create a graph from JSON received from a web API.

I had it working, and then decided to start refactoring.
After a while I suddenly noticed that the xAxis no longer shows dates, but instead it seems to be showing ticks.
I'm quite inexperienced with JavaScript and even more so with highcharts so I cannot spot my mistake.

[image: High Charts showing ticks.]
<sub>(source: [mortentoudahl.dk](http://mortentoudahl.dk/images/highchartsBug.png))</sub>

The change I did was making an option object, and pass it to highcharts upon instantiation, according to the instructions found here:
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options
When I compare my code to the last code block in that link, it seems to be the same, except for the options object.

```js
var pm10 = [];
var pm25 = [];


var options = {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  title: {
    text: "Compounds in the air at HCAB"
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ? 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : "Pinch the chart to zoom in"
  },
  xAxix: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'µg/m³'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Particles less than 2.5 µm',
    data: pm25,
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 8),
    pointInterval: 86400 * 1000 // One day
  }, {
    name: 'Particles less than 10 µm',
    data: pm10,
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 5, 8),
    pointInterval: 86400 * 1000 // One day
  }]
};

function ReverseAndSetArrays(data) {
  $.each(data.reverse(), function(key, value) {
    if ("PM10b" in value) {
      pm10.push(value["PM10b"]);
    };
    if (!("PM10b" in value)) {
      pm10.push(null);
    };
    if ("PM25b" in value) {
      pm25.push(value["PM25b"]);
    };
    if (!("PM25b" in value)) {
      pm25.push(null);
    };
  });
};

var url = "super secret url";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  ReverseAndSetArrays(data);
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You need to use xAxis object in your options, not xAxix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configuration in your options object is incorrect:

```
 xAxix: {
    type: 'datetime'
 }
```

It should be:

```
 xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
 }
```

Comment: Arghh - I was starring at this for so long before deciding to post here. Thanks for noticing